# Log4j2 not printing out logs in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j2

I was having some problem when trying to use log4j2 to log out messages in dynamic web project. Here is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="C:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\user_projects\\domains\\..\\trace.log">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>    
    </File>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
 <Root level="debug">
     <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
     <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
 </Root>
 </Loggers>
 </Configuration>
```

I commented out the absolute path, but in my local machine the specified path exists. I put the log4j2.xml under `/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml`. Then, in my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<display-name></display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mybatis.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- to load the system parameter -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartupServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sc.idms.common.startup.presentation.StartupServlet</servlet-class>

    ...

<!-- Spring MVC Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

However, when I run my web application, no logs has been printed in the log file. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named log4j2.xml in the classpath, so can you try removing <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param> and check if it works.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked 2 days ago? Have you tried including the log4j-web module and following http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html?

Comment: @Tanuj Unfortunately, nothing printed still. It only printed out when I moved the log4j2.xml under src folder but not /WEB-INF/... Do you have any ideas how to configure it so that I can place the log4j2.xml under /WEB-INF/... ?